# No visible @interface for 'BMPhotosViewController' declares the selector 'initWithPhoto:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I am getting:

> No visible @interface for 'BMPhotosViewController' declares the selector 'initWithPhoto:'

CODE:

```
if (image) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        BMPhotosViewController * photosVC = [[BMPhotosViewController alloc] initWithPhoto:@[[BMPhotoFullImage PhotoImageWithImage:image]]];

        [self.presentationViewController presentViewController:photosVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is Objective-C code, not Swift code. Please tag properly.

Comment: Look at the documentation for this 3rd party library to see what initializers do exist.

Answer (score 0):

if BMPhotosViewController is from a pod file, please check if the init method is publicly available in its header file, otherwise if its your own ViewController, simply declare the custom init method in the header's interface.

-(instancetype) initWithPhoto:(NSArray *)photos;

Comment: BMPhotosViewController.h imports NYTPhotosViewController.h and NYTPhotoViewController h and m files lie in a Pod directory. Any suggestions on where to add the custom init method?

Comment: i read the library, it has a custom init method as mentioned above, you are unable to access it as you have inherited the class in BMPhotosVC, what you can do is that in BMPhotosViewController header file, declare the

-(instancetype) initWithPhoto:(NSArray *)photos;

and then in its implementation

-(instancetype) initWithPhoto:(NSArray *)photos{
if( (self = [super initWithPhoto:photos]) ) {
        // do stuff and set up the fur based on the options
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: It still shows error; any suggestions if I should put BMPhotosViewController as return type instead of instancetype?

Comment: should'nt make any difference but you can try